# Javascript: array.push is undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have my code:

```
var name = [];
var mark1 = [];
var mark2 = [];
var mark3 = [];
var total = [];
count = 0
count2 = 0
var i = 0;
while (count != 2) {
  var nam = prompt("Enter name:")
  name.push(nam);
  var mk1 = prompt("Enter mark 1:");
  var mk1 = parseInt(mk1);
  mark1.push(mk1);
  var mk2 = prompt("Enter mark 2:");
  var mk2 = parseInt(mk2);
  mark2.push(mk2);
  var mk3 = prompt("Enter mark 2:");
  var mk3 = parseInt(mk3);
  mark3.push(mk3);
  var tot = mk1 + mk2 + mk3;
  total.push(tot)
  count = count + 1
  console.log(mk1 + mk2 + mk3);
  console.log(nam);
  console.log("the count is " + count)
};
```

When I run it I get an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

on Line 12 which is name.push(nam);

I have looked around but I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Help appreciated.

Comment: I can't reproduce that error with your code.

Comment: one important thing when asking for help is to make sure your code's properly indented. Humans like to be able to read things easily. Another is to confirm that's really what's going wrong. If we drop this code into jsbin.com or jsfiddle.net, it works just fine

Comment: no errors thrown here: http://jsfiddle.net/6yjwh1a5/

Comment: @BeNdErR your link wraps the code in a function, protecting the identifier conflict of the `var name` with `window.name`

Comment: May be you have skipped this line **var name = [];**, because of this line, this type of error is generated.

Comment: Sorry about my awful indentation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an interesting one. It all boils down to an unfortunate choice of variable name. Unfortunately `name` is a property of the `window` object. When you refer to `name` you are actually referring to window.name, not the array called `name`. If you rename `name` to something else, it should work just fine.